# Error with xlsx-style when building angular 6 app

Tags: excel, angular, xlsx, js-xlsx

I installed `xlsx-style` in my angular 6 app via yarn and I get `errors` when I build my app :

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/xlsx-style/dist/cpexcel.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './cptable' in 'C:\Users\cabannesj\Documents\Virga3\virga-frontend\node_modules\xlsx-style\dist'
ERROR in ../node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\cabannesj\Documents\Virga3\virga-frontend\node_modules\xlsx-style'
ERROR in ../node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\cabannesj\Documents\Virga3\virga-frontend\node_modules\xlsx-style'
```

I added `'xlsx.core.min.js'` in the script section of my `angular.json` file.

I don't know what is missing to get `xlsx-style` work with my app.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope, finally I use excel-js library.